# What are the wall-cleaners in climbing called? What equipment/gear do they use?

Tags: terminology, climbing

I have been watching this [climbing video of Alex Honnold](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Phl82D57P58).

In this video his friend goes ahead of him and cleans the wall of any debris or slippery rocks.

**What are these people who clean the walls for the climbers called?**  Or is it just the only one instance where a person actually cleaned a wall for the climber?

**What is the equipment used by these people?**

Comment: There is no "such people". In the video it is Alex Honnold himself and others who do the cleaning. This is just a normal process you might want to do before climbing new routes or routes that have not bee climbed for a long time (usually when soloing or if the route is very hard). If there are cleaning teams running around cleaning crags, I have never heard of them (of course locals my tend their local crag, but that is something else). So I think you should focus on your second question about what gear is used. That is a relevant question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**We used to call them 'wall sweepers'**

This is a wall that isn't climbed much.  You can see in the video there are some fresh bolts that have been put in and few old ones.  They are just using '[slings](https://www.google.com/search?q=carabiner%20slingshot&oq=carabiner%20sling&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l3.9290j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=carabiner%20sling) and [carabiners'](https://www.google.com/search?q=carbeaner&oq=carbeaner&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1849j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=carabiner) on their [harnesses](https://www.google.com/search?q=climbing%20harness&oq=climbing%20harness&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2816j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).  They might have some [cams](https://www.google.com/search?q=climbing%20cams&oq=climbing%20cams&aqs=chrome..69i57.3341j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) or some [nuts](https://www.google.com/search?q=climbing%20harness&oq=climbing%20harness&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2816j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=climbing%20wired%20nuts).  I did not see any on them though.  Only the slings and biners getting clipped into [pre-placed bolts](https://www.google.com/search?q=climbing%20bolts&oq=climbing%20bolts&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2225j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the help from [this amazing guy at Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/climbing/comments/4m5ko9/who_were_the_climbers_who_have_successfully/d3swqnt), I have got an answer for the question:

> Usually when you prepare a route for a first ascent you clean it, if
>   it gets a decent amount of traffic then no further cleaning should be
>   needed later on. But on alpine routes, long multi-pitches or big walls
>   you should always be careful of loose rock: too many meters to clean
>   for a first ascent party, and weathering produces new loose rock every
>   season. Water gets into cracks, freezes in winter and expands, and
>   boom, another piece of rock that just waits for you to rip it out or
>   fall on your head.
>
> > So, who are these people who clean the walls for the climbers called?
> >     Or is it just the only one instance where a person actually cleaned a
> >     wall for the climber?
>
> This is probably a rare occurrence where [Cedar Wright](http://www.cedarwright.com/#intro) put more
>   attention into it because Alex Honnold was about to free solo the
>   route. If you're on a rope then loose rock sucks and you might fall
>   because of it, but then the rope catches you.
>
> When you're free soloing you really dont want to grab any loose rock
>   because falling means you'll very likely die or be physically
>   disabled.
>
> > What are the equipment used by these people?
>
> It's been a while since i watched that video, but generally to get
>   around big walls you use fixed static lines and ascenders to get
>   up/down.